# Assembly Language x86 x[eax]

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm having troubles understanding what to do when I have x[eax]. Can anyone help? I can probably figure the rest from there. Here is my code:

```
.data
        X      BYTE     3, 9, 4, 0, 1, 7, 6, 2
.code 
main PROC
        MOV     EAX,    0
DEST_1: CMP     X[EAX], 0
        JE      DEST_2
        INC     EAX
        JMP     DEST_1
DEST_2: INC     EAX
```

Oh, another question. How do I get my result from EAX to AX?

Comment: That's just weird syntax for `[X + eax]`.  I think MASM allows this, and NASM might not.  AX is just the low half of EAX.  See the [tag:x86] tag wiki for links to guides, including a register diagram that shows how the partial regs are overlayed onto the wider ones.  So if you have a small integer in `eax`, you can just `mov [mem], ax` to store the low 16b.

Comment: Oh, okay thank you. I just want to make sure I understand. Since x[eax] is just [x+eax] I would add 8+0  then I would compare 0 with 8?

Comment: No, `[X+eax]` is an effective address, indexing into the `X` array.  `X[eax]` in the asm source does exactly the same thing as it would in C.  `X` is a symbol with an address, not the size of the array.

Comment: okay, makes more sense. I'm glad I asked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As Peter Cordes stated, X[EAX] is just an optional syntax for [X + EAX]. This is the form that the AT&T syntax uses, but it seems that MASM accepts it as well.

As far as "moving" EAX to AX, EAX is the 32-bit register and AX is the lower 16 bits of the same register, so as long as your value is only a 16 bit value, you should be fine unless it is a signed value. (AL is the lowest 8 bits, just in case you are curious.)

Comment: The AT&T version would be `X(%eax)`

Comment: Yea... AT&T doesn't use square brackets like that. I'm more comfortable with INTEL syntax. Thanks for pointing that out, Ninjalj.

Comment: Also, isn't that the typical Intel syntax? I think `OFFSET[BASE]` is more typical in older (think 8086 era) code than `[BASE + OFFSET]`

Comment: See: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html#HEADING2-105